# Macro to copy merged cell to another merged cell whilst keeping the formatting

Tags: vba, excel

As assisted below, I am currently using

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim src as Range, dest as Range
Dim mergeAddress as String
Set src = Range("C9")
Set dest = Worksheets("FRONT").Range("G7")
mergeAddress = dest.MergeArea.Address
If Not Intersect(Target,src) Is Nothing Then
dest.MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = src.Value
src.Copy
dest.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
dest.Parent.Range(mergeAddress).Merge
End If
End Sub
```

I am still losing the formatting with this code, e.g. bold, colour etc.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Merged cells are the Devil's work...

Comment: if you want to copy and paste merged cells, you will need to specify which ranges are merged, i.e. if you want to copy a merged cell, which originally consisted of range C9 and D9, then you will have to use `Range("C9","D9").Copy (Worksheets("FRONT").Range("G7"))`

Comment: @MarcoGetrost not exactly. Copying *from* merged cells is a little easier than copying *to* merged cells using the `MergeArea` property of a range object.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little tricky, perhaps this will help.  Merged Cells are a pain to work with. In this case, I think you can solve your problem by:

1. Get the address of the merged area
2. Copy/Paste formatting (this will unmerge the cells)
3. Re-merge the cells based on the address obtained in (1) above

**Copy FROM one cell to a Merged Area**

Here is the example I tested where [A1] has a MergeArea consisting of [A1:C3].  This example assumes you're copying ONE cell into a Merged Cell (e.g., "H1" gets copied in to "A1:C3"

```
Sub foo()
Dim src As Range, dest As Range
Dim mergeAddress As String

Set src = [H3]
Set dest = [A1]

'First, put the value in the merged cells:
dest.MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = src.Value = src.Value

'Then, the formatting:
'1. Get the mergeArea.Address
mergeAddress = dest.MergeArea.Address
'2. Copy & paste formatting (this unmerges the cells)
src.Copy
dest.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
'3. Re-merge the cells:
Range(mergeAddress).Merge

End Sub
```

Updating your code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim src as Range, dest as Range
Dim mergeAddress as String
Set src = Range("C9")
Set dest = Worksheets("FRONT").Range("G7")
mergeAddress = dest.MergeArea.Address
If Not Intersect(Target,src) Is Nothing Then
    dest.MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = src.Value
    src.Copy
    dest.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    dest.Parent.Range(mergeAddress).Merge
End If
End Sub
```

**Copy from Merged Area (full copy)**

Copying *from* merged cell is a little easier, where you can do the following, to copy the entire merged area, and paste to the destination:

```
src.MergeArea.Copy dest
```

Comment: Dear David, I've tested successfully `src.copy dest.MergeArea`, where dest is any cell from the merged area. Is there a problem with some versions of Excel or something?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking @A.S.H -- what is your question/problem?

Comment: I am saying that the copy operation worked for me as indicated, without the need to unmerge then merge the destination area. So I wonder if I misunderstood the reason for this complexity.

Comment: I wrote a simple macro with `Range("A1").Copy Destination:= Sheets("Sheet8").Range("H9").MergeArea` where `H9` is inside a large merged area... and it worked without problem. That made me wonder if I misunderstood the requirements question or if that would not work with some versions of Excel.

Comment: @A.S.H  I'm looking at Excel 2010 right now and when I do `src.Copy dest.MergeArea`, then the formatting doesn't carry through, only the `.Value`..  If i do simple `src.Copy dest` then 1004 "Can't change part of a merged cell"

Comment: I confirm. That is it then, bad me. Didnt see it in the question of the OP that they wanted to **keep the format**... But it is said in the title!! :D. My apologies.

Comment: I was just about to ask this.

The updated code you sent works perfectly but loses the formatting, anyway around this?

Comment: @TomShepherd the code I put for `Worksheet_Change` seems to work when I test it. If you're having trouble still, can you revise your Q and include the code you're currently attempting to use? I can take a look and see what the problem is.

Comment: Hey David, 

I am using the exact code above you posted altered for myself. 

It doesn't seem to carry over any of the formatting, I am using excel 2010 if that makes a difference. I have tried it on a brand new spreadsheet with identical amounts of merged cells moving to the same amount of merged cells.

Comment: **If you're having trouble still, can you revise your Q and include the code you're currently attempting to use? I can take a look and see what the problem is.**  Was that not clear the first time?

Comment: Ok I will do my best explaining it again.

I am attempting to move the contents of a cell from one worksheet to another and not lose the formatting (colour, font, bolding etc). The cell in which they are being transposed into is 100 or so merged cells forming a big reading pane on the form. 

I am using the update code you provided. I cannot paste it as it takes me over the word limit so I will post below. The code works to copy, but does not take the formatting with it.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Dim src as Range, dest as Range

    Dim mergeAddress as String
    Set src = Range("C9")
     Set dest = Worksheets("FRONT").Range("G7")
mergeAddress = dest.MergeArea.Address
If Not Intersect(Target,src) Is Nothing Then
    dest.MergeArea.Cells(1).Value = src.Value
    src.Copy
    dest.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    dest.Parent.Range(mergeAddress).Merge
End If
End Sub

Comment: What part of **REVISE YOUR ORIGINAL QUESTION** don't you understand?  Code doesn't belong in comments, as you can plainly see from the lack of formatting, indentation, etc.  Elaborate explanations also do not belong in the comments.

Comment: By revising your original Q, you're also allowing others to potentially help you. By putting all this in the comments only, you're basically limiting the audience to *only me*, which is not a good way to help yourself.

Comment: Right - as you can see I am basically brand new to not only using this forum but VBA. My apologies David.

Comment: This is also not a place for chit-chat. if you revise your question, I'll take a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: I think my original question and revised question was poorly worded, I stumbled across **xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme** and this was able to copy the rest of the formatting outside of the font positioning. Thanks for your help David with the answer it was very helpful, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

first: write a code to select a cell in the merged cell (It should select the whole merged cell)

second: write a code to copy the selected cells.

Example: I have spreadsheet with each day of the week in a row, but each day of the week is merged with columns "A" and "B". The code below will select and copy all the data including the rest of the merged cells.

```
Range(Cells.Find("Monday").Address, Cells.Find("Sunday").Address).Select
Selection.copy
```

to paste the data, use something along the lines of this:

```
Range("A30").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```